# Display a string of 1's and 0's in binary format Python

Tags: python, string, image, file, binary

Is there any way to actually get a string of 1's and 0's from a binary format ?

```
# read in image data
fh = open('test.png','rb')
data = fh.read()
fh.close()

# write binary to text file
fh = open('test.txt','w')
fh.write(data)
fh.close
fh.close()
```

how can i turn that data string into 1's and 0's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will convert each byte in your string to 8 binary digits and separate them with a space. You can easily change the separator.

```
data = " ".join(bin(ord(b))[2:].rjust(8, "0") for b in data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `with` so you don't have to explicitly close the fh

```
with open('test.txt','w') as fh:
    fh.write("".join(bin(ord(x))[2:].zfill(8) for x in data)
```

If the file is large, the above will use a lot of memory, instead you should read `data` in smaller chunks and call `write()` multiple times

Aside:
`fh.close` is just a reference to the method that closes the file. To call the method (ie close the file) you do need to say `fh.close()`